# How to apply for wireless debugging in Android?

Tags: usb, adb

I would like to know how programs such as sideQuest and Quest Games Optimizer apply for wireless debugging windows? What is the specific code?
I have connected to the computer and executed adb tcpip 5555, but I don’t know how my program can apply for a pop-up window to obtain debugging permissions.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtNCx.png)

This is the code I tried but it doesn't work

`function goToWirelessDebuggingSettings() local intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS) activity.startActivity(intent) end`